# Multiple containers in 1 pod with delay

Tags: kubernetes

I am still in the initial phase of understanding k8, so please forgive if you feel this lame. But I wanted to know if there is a way to have some kind of delay or ordered the execution of the containers in 1 single pod.
Let's say we have 1 Pod A and has 2 containers. For example, a kafka container exposing port 9092 and port 8081 and another container say a Kafka connect image which hits both of these ports. I wanted to know if there is a way to execute the Kafka container first and then execute Kafka connect container so that it won't get killed.

1) Can we have some delay or a sleep between 2 container creation?

2) Can we have some kind of priority of execution of containers within pods so that we can accomplish the above-mentioned situation?

PS: I have considered creating 2 pods and currently working on that. But also wanted to try to do this and also learn something new at the same time.Thanks.

Comment: In short, the answer of both question is 'NO'. But you can do some trick if you modify images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, but you could change the startup command for the second image to poll the availability of the ports of the first container through `localhost`. When both ports accept connections, then you know you can continue with starting up the application in the second image.

If you cannot modify the second image yourself, what you can do is create a config map which contains your own startup script using whatever scripting language you might have in the image. Mount the config map into the container at some path and then override the command run for the container in the pod definition (where depends on how you are deploying it), to invoke your script mounted in from the config map.

Your script can then do the polling, and when happy that first container is running okay, then it will execute the original command the container used to start the application.

If you were to use two pods instead, then you can still use the same idea, but rather than `localhost` use the hostname for the service of the first pod. In the two pod case, you could run the script in an init container instead of hijacking the original startup command of the actual image.

Answer (score 1):

What you want does not exist per se in Kubernetes as of early 2018 but you can use [init containers](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-pods-life/) to address some parts of your use case.

Comment: I assumed so after digging a lot about it. I just wanted some confirmation about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome but rather than thanking me, accept it as the correct answer, that's how we signal here others that follow after you what's important ;)

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas, I am afrain **InitContainer** will not work. Because, **initContainer** goes into completed phase. When **initContainer** goes into completed phase, you can't connect to its port. right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, init containers are most suited for one-off tasks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Feature Request for it: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65502

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Could you add some more details to the Feature Request directly in this post? (E.g. status, planned implementation date, ...)